# How to populate complex model with linq when datatables are different

Tags: c#, linq

How to populate complex model with linq when datatables are different for each source i.e. 
1 data table returns Employee and other table returns Dept and Address?

```
Sample Model below:

Public Class EmployeeData
{
  Public Employee Emp {get;set;}

}

Public Class Employee
{
   Public String EmployeeId {get;set;}
   Public String EmployeeName {get;set;}
   Public List<Department> Dep {get;set;}
}

Public Class Department
{
   Public String DepartmentId {get;set;}
   Public String DepartmentName {get;set;}
   Public List<Address> Addr {get;set;}
}

Public Class Address
{
   Public String AddrOne {get;set;}
   Public String City {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: You forgot to add datatables definitions - which columns you have? And what problem you have with populating model?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy - First table has EmpId, EmpName and 
second table has EmpId, DepartmentId, DepartmentName , AddrOne, City  .

Comment: department is 1 to many with address. And employee is 1 to many with departments. You need 3 tables here

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your datatable2 has duplicate DepartmentId rows for each department address

```
var emps = dataTable1.AsEnumerable().Select(r => new {
  EmpId = r["EmpId"].ToString(),
  EmpName = r["EmpName"].ToString(),
});
var depts = dataTable2.AsEnumerable().Select(r => new {
  EmpId = r["EmpId"].ToString(),
  DepartmentId = r["DepartmentId"].ToString(),
  DepartmentName = r["DepartmentName"].ToString(),
  AddrOne = r["AddrOne"].ToString(),
  City = r["City"].ToString(),
});
emps
  .Select(e => new EmployeeData {
    Emp = new Employee {
      EmployeeId = e.EmpId,
      EmployeeName = e.EmpName,
      Dep = depts.Where(w => w.EmpId == e.EmpId).GroupBy(g => new {
        DepartmentId = g.DepartmentId,
        DepartmentName = g.DepartmentName,
      })
      .Select(d => new Department {
        DepartmentId = d.Key.DepartmentId,
        DepartmentName = d.Key.DepartmentName,
        Addr = d.Select(a => new Address {
          AddrOne = a.AddrOne,
          City = a.City
        }).ToList(),
      }).ToList(),
    },
  });
```

NOTE:

- you'll need to add a reference to [System.Data.DataSetExtensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowextensions.aspx)
  for `AsEnumerable()` on `DatTable` which will return
  `IEnumerable<DataRow>`
- I am a little rusty on DataTables, please adjust accordingly